# Jquery operation on DOM element with '.' in ID has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

e.g. "Live" version here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltmbd/5/

```
<html>
     <body>
         <select id="some.list" >
            <option value="1" >AAA</option>
            <option value="2" >BBB</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

and corresponding javascript/jquery:

```
$(function()
{
    $("select").each(function()
    {
        $(this).val("2");
    });
});
```

This should select "BBB" in the select list (and if you remove the '.' from the ID "some.list", it works as expected).  Note that the [jquery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) mentions a related but slightly different problem.

The obvious answer is "don't put a . in your IDs" - however I'm using scaffolded (generated) grails views, so it would be a lot of work to go against this convention.

Using Jquery 1.4.4

Comment: Are you able to update your version of jQuery? The fiddle seems to work with all versions after 1.4.4.

Comment: Are you saying that even when your jQuery selector is not using the ID, like your examples `$("select")` and `$(this)` it will not work if the should-match element has a full stop (".") in its ID? Or does the problem only occur if you try to select by ID: `$("#some.list")`?

Comment: I think James's comment is right on. Looks like this was a bug and they fixed it. If that is absolutely not an option, all you can do is monkey-patch 1.4.4 to capture whatever fix they applied to address the issue (but if you can monkey-patch it, why not just upgrade?).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Check the fiddle linked to in the question. It seems to not work with `$("select")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery versions above 1.4.4 will do the trick.
consider updating your jQuery version and your problem should be solved, thanks.

Here is the original bug reported, and the case is that it's solved with the 1.5 release.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8021

Comment: There's no reason why I can't upgrade, so accepting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here another option for solving the problem. Hope this helps.

```
$(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('selectedIndex', 1);
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to stick to jQuery 1.4.4 for some reason, use `selectedIndex` to change the option value. It works, even with a dot in the ID.

```
this.selectedIndex = 1; //Select the second <option>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltmbd/6/**

Alternatively, you can use:

```
this.selectedIndex = $(this).find('option[value=2]').index();
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltmbd/10/**

Comment: Thanks for this workaround.  There are other cases where this bug is probably going to cause me problems though (i.e. not just selection an item in a list), so I'll go for upgrade as mentioned in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too much time on this even though i thought I had it right.
Turns out the 1.4.4 version seems to have a bug related to this. I went back to 1.3.2 and also any newer one and this worked.